# full width navbar collapses with screen

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie to web development and 99% of the time I can research and find my answer, but I have put forth the effort and done what I think I can. I have the feeling the issue is simple but it's just beyond my current abilities to solve right now.

I wanted a full width navbar spanning across the top of the site, with each link evenly spaced.

[This link](http://www.cssnewbie.com/full-width-centered-navigation-bar/#.WVATjWjyuUk) helped me accomplish something close to this, but had the elements centered and close together, which wasn't the style I was going for. Eventually by playing around with the margins of the left and right, I got the elements to be evenly spaced on my screen.

But when I click the maximize/restore button and the window gets smaller, my navbar collapses so that it's in two rows of three rather than one long row of six. The rest of the web page adjusts to the smaller window accordingly, but the navbar just seems to wrap around to fit.

My code (a variant of the [link I posted](http://www.cssnewbie.com/full-width-centered-navigation-bar/#.WVATjWjyuUk) above):

HTML

```
 <div id="nav">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Writers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Tales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Art</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #babbbc;
}
#nav li {
    margin: 0 115px 0 120px;;
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #727272;
    border-right: 1px hidden #ccc; }
#nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px hidden #ccc; }
```

Comment: Can you include the whole relevant code? Plus, please note that this article is from 2009. There are new methods for everything. would you like to know about a different approach?

Comment: I would love to know about a different approach. This is my first time posting, what else of the code should I post? I had tried other solutions and this one fit the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` as `display`. A `flexbox` auto-sets its `width` and `height` to spread all items evenly, if the property `flex-grow` is set to `1`. For the full width: set `width` to `100%`, and make sure that the parent element has a full size too, for example the `body`.

For more about the `Flexbox`: [here's a very detailed explanation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**Here's an example:**

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color:lawngreen;
  border: 4px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="nav">
      <ul>
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
          <li>item 4</li>
          <li>item 5</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much better than what I've had. Is there any way to make the margin between the links smaller based on the window size?

Comment: Yes, sure! Go to the explanation page, scroll down till you find the 'examples'. You can find the code of the example here: https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/EKEYob